# How to find $\delta$ for limit type questions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, homework

```
f[x_] := 2x + 3;
ε = 0.1; δ = 1; a = 0; L = 3;

fL[x_] = Abs[f[x] - L];

For[i = 1, i < 100, i++, 
  max = Quiet[MaxValue[{fL[x], 0 < Abs[x - a] < δ}, {x}]];
  If[max < ε, Break[]];
  δ = δ/2];

Print["Hence, |f(x)-L|<ϵ whenever 0<|x-a|<", δ ]
```

Question

> Let $f(x)$ be any function and $L$ be any number. For a given $a$ and $\varepsilon>0$, find a $\delta>0$ such that for all $x$ satisfying $0<|x-a|<\delta$, the inequality $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$ holds.

For $f(x)=2x+3, \varepsilon = 0.1, L = 3, a = 0$, I have written a program in *Mathematica* to find value of $\delta$.

My final output is;

> Hence, |f(x)-L|<ε whenever 0<|x-a|<1/32

But when I calculate $\delta$ manually, I get $\delta=\varepsilon$.

I want same thing from *Mathematica*. My program is giving me a $\delta$ for which solution is OK, but I want a symbolic result.

Comment: "But when I calculate δ manually..." - have you tried to implement what you do manually?

Answer (score 5):

Here's general way, limited by ability of `Reduce` to deal with the chosen function:

```
Block[{f, a, lim, eps, del, x},
 f[x_] := 2 x + 3;             (* set up problem *)
 lim = f[a];
 Reduce[del > 0 && eps > 0 &&  (* these will be carried through to the answer if needed *)
   ForAll[x, x ∈ Reals,        (* condition in the definition of limit *)
    0 < Abs[x - a] < del \[Implies] Abs[f[x] - lim] < eps],
  {del}, Reals]                (* "solve" for del *)
 ]

(*  eps > 0 && 0 < del <= eps/2  *)
```

This found all solutions `del`, but really we need only demonstrate one.  One could throw in a `Exists[del, del > 0,...]`, but you won't see a formula for `del` from which it can be deduced there is such a `del`.
For a numeric example, such as the example in the OP, one can use `FindInstance` to prove the existence of a `del`:

```
Block[{f, a, lim, eps, del, x},
 f[x_] := 2 x + 3;         (* set up problem *)
 a = 0;
 lim = f[a];
 eps = 1/10;
 FindInstance[del > 0 &&
   ForAll[x, x ∈ Reals, 
    0 < Abs[x - a] < del \[Implies] Abs[f[x] - lim] < eps],
  {del}, Reals]
 ]

(*  {{del -> 27/2021}}  *)
```

Here's another general existence proof, **assuming** `del` has a certain form `del == k * eps`, for some positive constant `k`.

```
Block[{f, a, lim, eps, del, x},
 f[x_] := 2 x + 3;
 a = 0;
 lim = f[a];
 FindInstance[k > 0 &&
   ForAll[eps, eps > 0,
    Exists[del, del == k*eps,    (* assumed form of del in terms of parameter k and eps *)
     ForAll[x, x ∈ Reals, 
      0 < Abs[x - a] < del \[Implies] Abs[f[x] - lim] < eps]
     ]],
  {k}, Reals]
 ]

(*  {{k -> 27/203}}  *)
```

For other functions, the form for `del` varies.  I'm not sure how best to guess the form. One might use `Series` and replace the condition `eps > 0` by something like `1 > eps > 0`.  It can also help to replace `k > 0` by `1 > k > 0`. Sometimes using an upper bound smaller than `1` helps.  Examples:

- For `x^2`, use `1 > eps > 0`; `a = 0` ==> `{{k -> 9/34}}`, `a = 1` ==> `{{k -> 27/244}}`.
- For `Surd[x, 3]` and `a = 0`, use `del == k*eps^3` ==> `{{k -> 9/34}}`.
- For `Surd[x, 3]` and `a = 1`, no change is necessary ==> `{{k -> 1/5}}`.

*[I seem to remember a similar Q&A but couldn't find it.]*

---

**General function**

This is based on the `FindInstance[]` solution above, and uses `Series` to guess what power to put on `eps` in `del == k * eps^pow`.

```
exponents = Cases[#,  (* sometimes `Series` produces a `Piecewise` result *)
    Verbatim[SeriesData][x_, _, c_, min_, _, den_] /; FreeQ[c, x] :> min/den,
    {0, Infinity}] &;

ClearAll[findDelta];
findDelta[f_, l_: Automatic, x_ -> a_] :=
  Module[{lim, pow, k}, Block[{eps, del},
    lim = l /. Automatic -> (f /. x -> a);  (* use function value for Automatic *)
    pow = Replace[
      exponents@Series[f - lim, {x, a, 2}],
      {{} :> (Print["Oops, no idea for form of del[eps]."]; $Failed),
       n_ /; Min[n] <= 0 :> (Print["Oops, nonpositive power suggests DNE."]; $Failed),
       n_ :> 1/Min[n]   (* inverse function gives the power to use *)
       }
      ];

    Condition[
     del == k*eps^pow /. 
      First@FindInstance[1 > k > 0 &&
         ForAll[eps, 1 > eps > 0,
          Exists[del, del == k*eps^pow,
           ForAll[x, x ∈ Reals, 
            0 < Abs[x - a] < del \[Implies] Abs[f - lim] < eps]
           ]],
        {k}, Reals],
     FreeQ[pow, $Failed]
     ]
    ]];
```

Examples:

```
findDelta[2 x + 3, x -> 0]      (*  del == (27 eps)/203  *)
findDelta[2 x^3, x -> 0]        (*  del == (27 eps^(1/3))/128  *)
findDelta[2 x^3, x -> 1]        (*  del == (27 eps)/698  *)
findDelta[Surd[x, 3], x -> 0]   (*  del == (9 eps^3)/34  *)

(* failures/errors: *)
findDelta[1/Log[Abs@Sin[x]]], 0, x -> 0]
(* Print:  Oops, no idea for form of del[eps].       *)
(* Out[]=  findDelta[1/Log[Abs@Sin[x]]], 0, x -> 0]  *)

findDelta[Exp[1/x], 0, x -> 0]
(* Errors: 1/0, ComplexInfinity                      *)
(* Print:  Oops, nonpositive power suggests DNE.     *)
(* Out[]=  findDelta[E^(1/x), 0, x -> 0]             *)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is a function that will return `δ` given `f`, `ε`, `a` and `L` (which I'm going to call `l` because upper case variables aren't a good idea in Mathematica). This is the function:

```
delta[f_, l_, a_, ε_] := Quiet[Min[Abs[a - x /. Solve[Abs[f[x] - l] == ε, x]]]]
```

With your example (and I'm defining `f` as a pure function):

```
f = 2 # + 3 &;
ε = 0.1;
a = 0;
l = 3;
δ = delta[f, l, a, ε]
```

> 0.05

So with `ε = 0.1` you need to set `δ < 0.05` so that `|f[x] - l| < ε`. Now we can check our answer:

```
MaxValue[{Abs[f[x] - l], a - δ < x < a + δ}, x]
```

> 0.1

as required.

It can also handle symbolic arguments (but I don't guarantee that it won't break easily):

```
ClearAll[ε]
δ = delta[f, l, a, ε]
```

> 0.5 Abs[ε]

That is, given any `ε > 0`, choose `δ < 0.5 ε`. Then `|f[x] - l| < ε`.

This function can handle marginally more complicated functions, like this cubic:

```
f = -#^3 + 3 #^2 + 2 # + 3 &;
ε = 0.1;
a = 1;
δ = delta[f, f[a], a, ε]
```

> 0.0200016

And as before

```
MaxValue[{Abs[f[x] - f[a]], a - δ < x < a + δ}, x]
```

> 0.1

as required.